"Solution (0) projects" when creating an ASP.NET Core Web API Project
Visual Studio 2022 here, Community Edition.
Whenever I try to create a project using the template "ASP.NET Core WEB API" it creates nothing. It shows me "Solution [name] (0) project

What is the problem? I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio to no avail.
Here's some screenshots of the installer:


Did any file exist inside the created folder and what happened if you running the dotnet --info inside the CMD?

No, there is no file in the created folder. What should I run in CMD?

dotnet --info this command


Try creating a new ASP.NET Core Web API project using the dotnet command-line interface (CLI) instead of Visual Studio. dotnet new webapi -n MyWebApi
you can try resetting Visual Studio settings to their default values. Go to "Tools" > "Import and Export Settings" > "Reset all settings".

